# Webpack two applications in one bundle, Angular requires Zone.js

Tags: angular, webpack, bundle, zone.js

Hello everyone I am building two angular applications in one bundle with webpack. The applications are in the src folder.

Here is my webpack config

```
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');              
const webpack = require('webpack');                               
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');                    
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;                    
const path = require('path');                                     
const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');        

// Webpack Plugins                                                
const CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;   
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {                  

  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',                              

  entry: {                                                     
      polyfills: './src/app-integration/polyfills.ts',              
      main: ['./src/app-integration/main.ts', './src/app-integration/styles/css/app.css'],                                 
      spa_test: './src/spa-test/main.ts'                               
  },                                                              

  output: {                                                         
      path: root('dist'),                                       
      filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',                     
      chunkFilename: 'js/[id].chunk.js'                                
  },                                                              

  module: {                                                        
    rules: [                                                          
    // Loads external css styles into the DOM                          
    {                                                              
       test: /\.(css|scss)$/,                                       
       use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],  
       include: [root('src/app-integration', 'styles', 'css')]        
    },                                                                  
    {                                                               
       test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,         
       loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack']                                   
    }                                                                   
   ]                                                                    
  },                                                             

  plugins: [

    // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      minChunks: function (module) {
        return module.resource && module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules)
      },
      chunks: [
        "main"
      ]
    }),


    new AngularCompilerPlugin({
      "mainPath": "./src/app-integration/main.ts",
      "tsConfigPath": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "skipCodeGeneration": false
    }),

    // Inject script and link tags into html files
    // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/app-integration/index.html',
      chunksSortMode: function (a, b) {
        var order = ["polyfills", "vendor", "main", "styles"];
        return order.indexOf(a.names[0]) - order.indexOf(b.names[0]);
      }
    }),                                                                      
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename : 'spa_test.html',                             
      template: './src/spa-test/index.html'
    })                                                               
   ],                                                                  

  /**                                                                   
   * Dev server configuration                                           
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver                
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html  
   */                                                          
   devServer: {
     historyApiFallback: true,
     stats: {
     colors: true,
     hash: true,
     timings: true,
     chunks: false,
     chunkModules: false,
     children: false, // listing all children is very noisy in AOT and hides warnings/errors
     modules: true,
     maxModules: 0,rules: [

     reasons: false,
     warnings: true,
     assets: false, // listing all assets is very noisy when using assets directories
     version: false
   }, // none (or false), errors-only, minimal, normal (or true) and verbose,

   watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 },
     open:true,
     overlay: true                                                        
   },                                                                  

  node: {
    global: true,
    crypto: 'empty',
    process: true,
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }                                                                 
});                                                                 

// Helper functions                                            
function root(args) {                                              
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);               
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));             
}
```

When I run the command `npm run webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --profile --port 8000` which builds the two apps and runs the first one (app-integration) on port 8000, I get the following error `Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js` in browser console. This error appeared after that I added the second application (spa-test) in my project.

I can add more information about this problem if it is necessary.

UPDATE -------------------------

The applications are running at the same time and there is a polyfills file which loads zone.js for the first app. Zone.js is never loaded for the second app and it can be loaded just once.

This is the cause of the error `Error: In this configuration Angular requires Zone.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing npm dependency `zone.js`. Run `npm install --save zone.js` and then try again.

To give you more insight: Angular needs `zone.js`. A pretty good (rather old) article [here](https://medium.com/@MertzAlertz/what-the-hell-is-zone-js-and-why-is-it-in-my-angular-2-6ff28bcf943e).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rakesh, zone.js is already installed. In fact the problem is more complicated, I have two application which are running at the same dtime and one polyfills which loads zone.js for the first app. Zone.js is never loaded for the second and it can be loaded just once.